# Javascript new keyword in subfunctions

Tags: javascript

I´m trying to sort out how 'new' keyword is working in Javascript. But it is has a strange behaviour.
When I run this code in node:

```
var testing = function() {
  self = this;
  this.abc = 'abc';
  console.log(this); // ====> 1

  var subMethod = function () {
    console.log(this);  // =====> 2
    console.log(self === this); // ====> 3
  };
  //subMethod.apply(this);
  subMethod();
};


test = new testing();
// test = testing(); // ===> *4
```

The console.log(self === this) gives me false. 
'this' in nr 1 is { abc: 'abc' }, and 'this' in the sub method is the global 'this' object. Can anyone give me an explanation for this behaviour?

If I run with subMethod.apply(this) then console.log(self === this) is true ({ abc: 'abc' })

When I run without the new keyword (*4) the 'this' variable is the same as the global 'this' (as expected), and also the console.log(self === this) is true.
    
 Why is 'this' in the submethod the same as the global 'this' when running with the 'new' keyword.

Comment: When applying this.subMethod = function.... . Then the this scope is as I expect { abc: 'abc', subMethod: [Function] }

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102 It doesn't *explicitly* discuss `new` but there's really nothing special about it -- it works exactly as you'd expect; the closures are the tricky bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `new testing()`, the function `testing` is run with its context (`this`) as a new object. The first log will be that object. Inside, when you run `subMethod()`, it's run in the global context. That's just how JS does it. Therefore, `this` is `window`, and `self !== this`. If you call it with your `this` context (`subMethod.apply(this)`), so naturally `self === this`.

When you call `testing()`, it's run in global context. When you add `abc`, that's now global, as `this` is `window`. When you call `subMethod()`, it's also called in global context by default, and as such `self === this`.

So basically, running a plain function is in global context. Running a function as a constructor (with `new`) creates a new context. Running a method (e.g. `"abaca".split('a')`) is called in the context of the base object - `split` is called with `"abaca"` as its `this`.

Does that help?